# Reading an online XML file with VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need to make an application in which a vb.net application takes in a XML file from a url and display it in my program. An example of a place to get a url would be www.example.com/yx3234.xml then take the contents of this and read it into my program.

Comment: This is a very open question. There are lots of pieces to this.

Comment: Any suggestions on refining it?

Comment: There are just so many pieces. You say "online." Where exactly? XML files have lots of "parts." What exactly do you want to do with those parts. Have you tried anything? What went wrong? My guess is that your question is going to be closed soon.

Comment: are you trying to read an rss feed possibly?

Comment: No, I want to read information from a url like this http://battless59.evony.com/default.html?logfile/20111121/4c/6b/4c6b0c2f1ca16b8dbdf971154741dd4c.xml .

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Have you looked at the WebClient class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Linq XML`. You can pass the uri to `XDocument.Load()` method.

```
Dim doc As XDocument
doc = XDocument.Load("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8842115/sample.xml")
For Each node In doc.Descendants("first")
  Console.WriteLine(CType(node.Element("no"), String))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to show you how you can download a web page from the Internet into a string in your Vb.Net program. You need to create a new WebClient class instance and then specify the URL you want to download as the parameter to the DownloadString method, which will return a string containing the HTML source (or XML in your case). If no accept-encoding is specified, the server usually returns a plain text string.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net

Class Program
    Private Shared Sub Main()
        ' Create web client.
        Dim client As New WebClient()

        ' Download string.
        Dim value As String = client.DownloadString("http://battless59.evony.com/default.html?logfile/20111121/4c/6b/4c6b0c2f1ca16b8dbdf971154741dd4c.xml")

        ' Write values.
        Console.WriteLine("--- WebClient result ---")
        Console.WriteLine(value.Length)
        Console.WriteLine(value)
    End Sub
End Class
```